# Compile-time check if a name is defined

Tags: haskell, embedded

Is it possible to check if a function is defined, and use it as the `Just` value of a `Maybe` type if it is? And use `Nothing` if it's not defined, of course.

I'm writing a wrapper around [atom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/atom) for use with the TI [MSP430](http://www.ti.com/msp430) line. Part of what I'm doing is making a function that quickly compiles the code in the right format for MSP430 controllers - for example, compiling an atom to use in a timer interrupt requires a function definition like so:

```c
#pragma vector=TIMERA0_VECTOR __interrupt
void timerAisr(void) {
    ...
}
```

At the moment, I have an object that holds references to the function the user would like to use for each different ISR. It looks a bit like this:

```hs
mspProgram = MSP430Compilation {
    setupFn = Nothing,
    setupFnName = "setup",
    loopFn = Nothing,
    loopFnName = "loop",
    timerAISR = Nothing,
    timerAISRName = "timerAISR",
```

And so on. Very configurable - you can choose the name of the function to output in C code, and the Atom to compile for that function. But I've decided I'd like to take more of a convention-over-configuration approach and basically assume some sensible function names. So instead of passing one of these configuration objects, I want the compilation code to check for definitions of sensibly-named functions.

For example, if the user defines an Atom called timerAISR, then my code should compile that atom to a C function named the same, with the appropriate `#pragma` matter for it to service the timer A interrupt.

So what I need to do is sort of meta-Haskell, checking if the user has defined a function and using that in my library code. I imagine this might involve template Haskell, so I'm off to research it.

EDIT:

I've realised that my original solution was too simplistic once I tried to fit it into my actual code. I hadn't absorbed Haskell's namespacing, so I didn't realise that `lookupValueName` would not work on values defined in user code. Here's the situation I'm dealing with:

`main.hs`:

```
module Main where
import Library

a = 1

main = libraryMain
```

`Library.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Library where
import Template

libraryMain :: IO ()
libraryMain = do
    $(printSomethingIfIsDefined "a")
    $(printSomethingIfIsDefined "b")
```

`Template.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Template where
import Language.Haskell.TH

printSomethingIfIsDefined name = do
maybeFn <- lookupValueName name
case maybeFn of
    Just fn -> [| putStrLn "It's defined!" |]
    Nothing -> [| return () |]
```

This prints nothing. If I define `a` in `Library.hs`, it will print out once, because `a` is defined in that scope.

Comment: Note that this checking happens at Haskell's compile-time. Usually users write their code, then `runhaskell myProgram.hs`, which compiles the Haskell and then runs it, which generates the C code.

Comment: You should also be aware that GHC has an option to provide a custom preprocessor. Theoretically you could use that to scan your source file and insert default functions if the user didn't provide any. http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#pre-processor

Comment: If you're using dynamically loaded code, you can query modules for the existence of functions. It depends how you're treating your source.

Comment: @MikeHartl That's an interesting option, though I'd prefer to not deal with writing a preprocessor.

Comment: @DonStewart Basically, my compilation function is in a module included by client code, and invoked in their main function. So I suspect not.